# Accelerometer API for windows mobile 6

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, accelerometer

I am writing an application for WIM 6, and one of its features is to detect no movement. How can I access the phone's accelerometer? is there any managed API that wraps it so I can write it on c#?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library [available here](http://sensorapi.codeplex.com/) that works on many HTC devices.

Comment: Nice to know, its really nice API :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent article with sample code in MSDN Magazine: "Shake and Skip to Interact with Your Music"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee413721.aspx

that should get You started.